# Adding a short int to an unsigned char pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm looking for a way to append the string representation of a `short int` to an existing string (stored in an `unsigned char*`).

The only thing I think that could do it is by using `memcpy()` but I'd like an example if that's the thing I need to use.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? And show us what you have tried.

Comment: "I would like to add an elephant to a mouse, the only thing i think that could do it is by using a mower. " that's what your question sounds like :)

Comment: I have a premade unsigned char* that holds data. This is code I get from a method I can't edit. I want to add a short int value at the end of this data. I have no code to show since I don't know where to start
@Drax: I need it as a unsigned char*

Comment: Aha. So you wish to _append_ a short int, as a string, to an existing string (stored in an unsigned char*)?

Comment: If you could do it like that then yes :)

Comment: @Dries Only "data" a pointer can *hold* is an address. Do you mean it points to an *array* (of data)? If so, does the method you get it from allocate any extra space for you to add the short int.

Comment: so in case when you have a string "best number is: " and short = 4444 you want to get what output?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  This treats the unsigned char * as a string and 'appends' the string representation of a short int to it.

Not much to say except...

1) Using unsigned char to represent strings is highly unusual.  I'd say your first step is to convert it to a normal character pointer.

2) Printf is your best friend when working with C style strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Returns a newly allocated buffer containing string concatenated with the string representation of append_me
char * append (char * string, short int append_me)
{
  // Assume that the short int isn't more than 5 characters long (+1 for space, +1 for possible negative sign)
  char * result = new char[strlen(string) + 7];
  sprintf (result, "%s %hd", string, append_me);
  return result;
}

// Just a wrapper method to abstract away unsigned char * nonsense.
unsigned char * append (unsigned char * string, short int append_me)
{
  return (unsigned char *)append ((char *) string, append_me);
}

int main()
{
  // Not sure why we're using unsigned char, but okay...
  unsigned char * the_string = (unsigned char *)"Hello World!";

  the_string = append (the_string, 574);

  printf ("%s\n", the_string);

  // We're responsible for cleaning up the result of append!
  delete[] (the_string);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: My rule of thumb is to use C string API for C strings and C++ string API for C++ strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your number as **string** like: string="ala" and number=20 you want to get result="ala20" instead of using raw pointers (which in most cases is unnecessary when it comes to C++), you can just use `std::stringstream`, which can let you append any simple type (and strings):

```
std::stringstream myStream;
myStream << "I have ";
myStream << 2;
myStream << " apples.";
std::cout << myStream.str() << std::endl;
```

Which will gave you output:

```
I have 2 apples.
```

If you want to serialize short to char buffer (copy it byte to byte), you can use `memcpy` :

```
memcpy(&buffer[offset], &value, sizeof(value));
```

Of course you need to have enough memory after `buffer+offset`.

You didn't state, what is the purpose of this operation. If it's for displaying purposes (like the first one), then `std::stringstream` is the way to go. If you are saving some data to file or passing them through socket, the second one has less memory consumption - for max value of `short` (32767) first version will need 5B (amount of digits - 1B per digit), when second version will hold any value of short on 2B (assuming `short` size is 2B).